# comprobación captcha no funciona

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Tengo un formulario para agregar usuarios que funcionaba bien, pero le puse un captcha muy básico que he creado yo mismo, pero no sé por qué no me funciona.
Le he dado mil vueltas y he modificado la página mil veces, pero no consigo nada de nada.
No utilizo ni puedo utilizar nada de Javascript, solo php con html.
El captcha lo probé aparte y funcionaba perfectamente bien, pero al unirlo al formulario ya no.
A continuación pongo todo el código de la página porque hay varios sitios donde puede estar el posible error:

```
<?php
    require('includes/config.php');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["num1"]=rand(0,100);
    $_SESSION["num2"]=rand(0,100);
    $_SESSION["num3"]=rand(0,100);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>CHARLYBANK</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            <h1>Creación de usuario CHARLYBANK</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="nombre"><b>Introduce el nombre:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="apellidos"><b>Introduce los apellidos:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" name="apellidos" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="telefijo"><b>Introduce el teléfono fijo:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="Teléfono fijo" name="telefijo" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="telemovil"><b>Introduce el teléfono móvil:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="Teléfono móvil" name="telemovil" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="email"><b>Introduce el correo electrónico:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="fechanac"><b>Introduce la fecha de nacimiento:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" name="fechanac" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="direccion"><b>Introduce la dirección:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" name="direccion" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="codpostal"><b>Introduce el código postal:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="Código postal" name="codpostal" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="poblacion"><b>Introduce la población:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Población" name="poblacion" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="region"><b>Introduce la región:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Región" name="region" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="pais"><b>Introduce el país:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="País" name="pais" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="username"><b>Introduce el nombre de usuario:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="username" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="password"><b>Introduce la contraseña:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td colspan="2"><label><input type="checkbox" name="acepto" required> Acepto los términos y condiciones.</label></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><label for="captcha"><b>Resuelve la operacion:
                        <?php echo $_SESSION["num1"]; ?> + <?php echo $_SESSION["num2"]; ?> - <?php echo $_SESSION["num3"]; ?>:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="Captcha" name="captcha" required></td></tr>
                    <tr class="fila"><td><input type="submit"name="aceptar" value="Aceptar"></td>
                    <td><input type="reset"name="cancelar" value="Cancelar"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </section>
        <?php
            function comprobar_email($email){
                return (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))?1:0;
            }
            function comprobar_username($username){
                require('includes/config.php');
                try{
                    $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username');
                    $sql->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
                    $row=$sql->fetch();
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                if($row){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function comprobar_contraseña($password){
                if(strlen($password)<6){
                    echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos seis caracteres!";
                    return false;
                }
                if(strlen($password)>20){
                    echo "La contraseña no debe tener más de veinte caracteres!";
                    return false;
                }
                if(!preg_match('`[a-z]`',$password)){
                    echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos una letra minúscula!";
                    return false;
                }
                if(!preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$password)){
                    echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos una letra mayúscula!";
                    return false;
                }
                if(!preg_match('`[0-9]`',$password)){
                    echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos un caracter numérico!";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            function validar_captcha($num1,$num2,$num3,$captcha){
                $resp=$num1+$num2-$num3;
                if($resp==$captcha){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(isset($_POST["aceptar"])){
                $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
                $apellidos=$_POST["apellidos"];
                $telefijo=$_POST["telefijo"];
                $telemovil=$_POST["telemovil"];
                $email=$_POST["email"];
                $fechanac=$_POST["fechanac"];
                $direccion=$_POST["direccion"];
                $codpostal=$_POST["codpostal"];
                $poblacion=$_POST["poblacion"];
                $region=$_POST["region"];
                $pais=$_POST["pais"];
                $username=$_POST["username"];
                $password=$_POST["password"];
                $captcha=$_POST["captcha"];
                if(!comprobar_email($email)){
                    echo "El formato de email NO es correcto!";
                }else{
                    if(comprobar_username($username)==true){
                        echo "El nombre de usuario ya existe!";
                    }else{
                        if(comprobar_contraseña($password)==false){
                            echo "La contraseña NO es correcta!";
                        }else{
                            if(validar_captcha($_SESSION["num1"],$_SESSION["num2"],$_SESSION["num3"],$captcha)==false){
                                echo "NO existe captcha!";
                            }else{
                                if(isset($_POST["acepto"])){
                                    $hash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                                    try{
                                        $sql=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO users 
                                        (nombre,apellidos,telefijo,telemovil,email,fechanac,direccion,codpostal,poblacion,region,pais,username,password) VALUES 
                                        (:nombre,:apellidos,:telefijo,:telemovil,:email,:fechanac,:direccion,:codpostal,:poblacion,:region,:pais,:username,:password)');
                                        $sql->execute(array(
                                            ':nombre'=>$nombre,
                                            ':apellidos'=>$apellidos,
                                            ':telefijo'=>$telefijo,
                                            ':telemovil'=>$telemovil,
                                            ':email'=>$email,
                                            ':fechanac'=>$fechanac,
                                            ':direccion'=>$direccion,
                                            ':codpostal'=>$codpostal,
                                            ':poblacion'=>$poblacion,
                                            ':region'=>$region,
                                            ':pais'=>$pais,
                                            ':username'=>$username,
                                            ':password'=>$hash
                                        ));
                                        header('Location:account_accept.php');
                                        exit;
                                    }catch(PDOException $e){
                                        echo $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    echo "Se deben aceptar los términos del contrato!";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
        <footer id="footer" style="bottom:-350px;">
            <p>&copy; 2019 Charlybank</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías detalar el **no funciona**?, ¿algun mensaje de error?, ¿no aparecen los números?

Comment: creo que en el metodo de comprobacion va al else, sale false y aparece el echo de que no existe captcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es el siguiente.
El inicio de tu pagina en PHP le otorgas un valor a cada variables de session, el cual es random entre el 1 y el 100.

```
$_SESSION["num1"]=rand(0,100);
$_SESSION["num2"]=rand(0,100);
$_SESSION["num3"]=rand(0,100);
```

Por otro lado tu formulario, en el cual muestras estos valores para que haga la operacion matematica para poder comprobar (captcha) apunta a ninguna pagina en especifico mediante `POST`. Eso quiere decir que al enviar el formulario estaras cargando nuevamente el la misma pagina.

Al cargar nuevamente la pagina los valores de su session se nuevamente se cambiaran, por que la vuelves a cargar y se vuelve a asignar. Por esta razon no podrás comprobar.

Posibles soluciones.
1.- Almacenar el resultado de tu operacion en un input hidden, el cual puedes comprobar con el resultado que el usuario ha ingresado.

```
<input type="hidden" name="resultado" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["num1"] + $_SESSION["num2"] - $_SESSION["num3"]; ?>">
```

```
$resultado=$_POST["resultado"];
$captcha=$_POST["captcha"];

function validar_captcha($resultado,$captcha){
    if($resultado==$captcha){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Al llamar esta funcion pasandole los parametros retornara `true` o `false`

2.- La otra alternativa, la cual te recomiendo mas.
Es que todo el código que acá pusiste, ***hasta el formulario*** ,lo tengas en tu pagina1.php

Y crees una pagina2.php donde  pondrias tu codigo de comprobación y eventual inserción a tu tabla.

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php');
session_start();


function comprobar_email($email){
    return (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))?1:0;
}
function comprobar_username($username){
    require('includes/config.php');
    try{
        $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username');
        $sql->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
        $row=$sql->fetch();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($row){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
function comprobar_contraseña($password){
    if(strlen($password)<6){
        echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos seis caracteres!";
        return false;
    }
    if(strlen($password)>20){
        echo "La contraseña no debe tener más de veinte caracteres!";
        return false;
    }
    if(!preg_match('`[a-z]`',$password)){
        echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos una letra minúscula!";
        return false;
    }
    if(!preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$password)){
        echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos una letra mayúscula!";
        return false;
    }
    if(!preg_match('`[0-9]`',$password)){
        echo "La contraseña debe tener al menos un caracter numérico!";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function validar_captcha($num1,$num2,$num3,$captcha){
    $resp=$num1+$num2-$num3;
    if($resp==$captcha){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
if(isset($_POST["aceptar"])){
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $apellidos=$_POST["apellidos"];
    $telefijo=$_POST["telefijo"];
    $telemovil=$_POST["telemovil"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $fechanac=$_POST["fechanac"];
    $direccion=$_POST["direccion"];
    $codpostal=$_POST["codpostal"];
    $poblacion=$_POST["poblacion"];
    $region=$_POST["region"];
    $pais=$_POST["pais"];
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $captcha=$_POST["captcha"];
    if(!comprobar_email($email)){
        echo "El formato de email NO es correcto!";
    }else{
        if(comprobar_username($username)==true){
            echo "El nombre de usuario ya existe!";
        }else{
            if(comprobar_contraseña($password)==false){
                echo "La contraseña NO es correcta!";
            }else{
                if(validar_captcha($_SESSION["num1"],$_SESSION["num2"],$_SESSION["num3"],$captcha)==false){
                    echo "NO existe captcha!";
                }else{
                    if(isset($_POST["acepto"])){
                        $hash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        try{
                            $sql=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO users 
                            (nombre,apellidos,telefijo,telemovil,email,fechanac,direccion,codpostal,poblacion,region,pais,username,password) VALUES 
                            (:nombre,:apellidos,:telefijo,:telemovil,:email,:fechanac,:direccion,:codpostal,:poblacion,:region,:pais,:username,:password)');
                            $sql->execute(array(
                                ':nombre'=>$nombre,
                                ':apellidos'=>$apellidos,
                                ':telefijo'=>$telefijo,
                                ':telemovil'=>$telemovil,
                                ':email'=>$email,
                                ':fechanac'=>$fechanac,
                                ':direccion'=>$direccion,
                                ':codpostal'=>$codpostal,
                                ':poblacion'=>$poblacion,
                                ':region'=>$region,
                                ':pais'=>$pais,
                                ':username'=>$username,
                                ':password'=>$hash
                            ));
                            header('Location:account_accept.php');
                            exit;
                        }catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "Se deben aceptar los términos del contrato!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la solución de poner un campo oculto me funciono perfectamente.